# Random background changing only works on firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, background-image

My code seems to run perfect on Firefox. But when I want to run it on IE or Chrome, my background seems to be blank. Is there something wrong with my code? Or is it simply not supported on the browsers I tested it on?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {
     var imgs = [
        'images/1.jpg',
        'images/2.jpg',
        'images/3.jpg',
        'images/4.jpg',
        'images/5.jpg',
        'images/6.jpg'
     ];
     document.body.style = 'background: url(' + imgs[Math.round(Math.random() * imgs.length)] + ') no-repeat ; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;';
    }
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <?php include ("header.php"); ?>
    <div align="center" >
        <?php include ("main.php"); ?>
        <?php include ("footer.php"); ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: An error message of some sort would help.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it better to use `style.cssText`?

```
document.body.style.cssText = 'background: url(' + imgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length)] + ') no-repeat ; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;';
```

Also, it seems that `Math.round(Math.random() * imgs.length)` can sometimes produce `imgs.length` as the result and exceed the array boundary, so I'd suggest `Math.floor` instead.

Comment: Yes your right on both parts. Thanks for noticing! This works flawless.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong. It should be:

```
var body = document.body;
body.style.background = 'url(' + imgs[Math.round(Math.random() * imgs.length)] + ') no-repeat';
body.style.webkitBackgroundSize = 'cover';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CGsxB/

Setting a bunch of properties at once as a string might work in Firefox, but in general you should set individual style properties separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<script>
function my_function() {
 var imgs = [
    'images/1.jpg',
    'images/2.jpg',
    'images/3.jpg',
    'images/4.jpg',
    'images/5.jpg',
    'images/6.jpg' ];
 document.body.style = 'background: url(' + imgs[Math.round(Math.random() * imgs.length)] + ') no-repeat ; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;';

 //also you can try like
    document.getElementByTagName('body').style = 'background: url(' + imgs[Math.round(Math.random() * imgs.length)] + ') no-repeat ; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;';
}
  my_function();   //Just call this 
</script>
```

It will call the `my_function()` on each page load.Because `window.onload` **may** not support for all the browsers and their versions

Comment: It seems highly unlikely to me the `window.onload` may not be supported.